# PLSQL function compilation errors when using Oracle data pump

Tags: oracle, plsql, datapump

I have two PLSQL functions in an Oracle database. Function A uses function B. Therefore to compile function A successfully function B must already be there.

When I use data pump to import the functions it is importing function A before function B, causing a compilation error. I then have to go into SQL Developer and recompile the function before it will work.

My question is, is there any way of making data pump import functions/procedures so that dependecies are loaded in first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change it unless you load them separately (dependent objects first).

---

It is likely not worth the hassle - your invalid procedure will be automatocally recompiled on next call. And if it compiles in moment you call it - all is ok.

---

If you prefer you can try to compile all invalid objects at the end of import (user_objects.status = 'INVALID' ). There is also sql script in oracle server rdbms/admin directory...